# let $x,y ,z \in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $x \geq y \geq z$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 2xy+2xz+2yz$ now find the $\text{min}(\dfrac{x}{z})=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, maxima-minima

> Let $x,y ,z \in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $x \geq y \geq z$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 2xy+2xz+2yz$. Find $\text{min}\bigg(\dfrac{x}{z}\bigg)= \ ?$

I found $(x-y+z-2\sqrt{xz})(x-y+z+\sqrt{xz})\geq 0$ 
but now what do I do?

Comment: Much how I changed the size of brackets in the edit, I let you have the opportunity to change the size of brackets in the title. Just use **\bigg($\ldots$\bigg)** or **\left($\ldots$\right)**.

Answer (score 6):

Since $x \ge y \ge z > 0$, we have $x \ge x - y + z > 0$. This leads to

$$\begin{align}x^2 \ge (x-y+z)^2 &= x^2+y^2+z^2 -2(xy+yz-xz)\\
&= 4xz + (x^2+y^2+z^2 - 2(xy+yz+xz)) \\
&\ge 4xz\end{align}$$
As a result, $\displaystyle\;\frac{x}{z} \ge 4$. Notice this ratio $4$ is achievable at $(x, y, z) = (4, 1, 1)$ which satisfies the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 2(xy+yz+zx)$, this is the minimal value of $\displaystyle\;\frac{x}{z}$.

**Update**

About the side question how I have solved this problem. I didn't solve it by algebra. The first thing I do is figure out what are the
domain of $(x,y,z)$ subject to the constraints:

1. $x \ge y \ge z > 0$.
2. $x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 2(xy+yz+xz) \iff 2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ge (x+y+z)^2$.

Notice the constraints are homogeneous, i.e. if $(x,y,z)$ satisfy the constraints,
so do any scalar multiple $(\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z)$ for $\lambda > 0$.
This means we can restrict out attention to those $(x,y,z)$ lies on the plane $x + y + z = 1$.

Constraint $1$ tell us the $(x,y,z)$ belongs to one-sixth of the equilateral triangle with vertices $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$. Constraint $2$ tell us $(x,y,z)$ is lying outside a circle on that equilateral triangle.
The resulting domain is a triangular like shape bounded by two straight lines
and a circular arc.

If one play around the values of $\frac{z}{z}$ along the boundary of this domain, one will find the minimum is achieved at the vertex $(\frac23,\frac16,\frac16)$ with value $4$. Knowing the answer is $4$, one can look back at the algebra and try to find a way to get that. The rest is really trial and error.

In short, in order to solve this problem, I use following sort of well known approach:

> First guess the right answer by whatever means and then justify it.

Comment: Hi! if I may ask, how do you approach these sort of problems in general? There are soo many algebraic manipulations you can do, but you chose the right ones. Also, do you have a feeling for when passing to a smaller expression by $>$ is not giving away too much?

Comment: why $ 4xz + (x^2+y^2+z^2 - 2(xy+yz+xz))  \ge 4xz$

Comment: @Ovi it is just about remembering different systems of equations to know what kind of equations to apply in these sorts of problems, but there may also be many methods. For example, find $m^3 + \dfrac{1}{m^3}$ if $m + \dfrac 1m = 2$. We can use the formula $(x + y)^3 = x^3 + y^3 + 3xy(x + y)$ and thus $$m^3 + \frac{1}{m^3} = \bigg(m + \frac 1m\bigg)^3 - 3\cdot m\cdot \frac 1m \bigg(m + \frac 1m\bigg)$$ and realise that $m^3 + \dfrac{1}{m^3} = 8 - 6 = 2$. Or, I could multiply $m$ by both sides of the equation $m+\dfrac 1m = 2$ and solve for $m$ in $m^2-2m+1 = 0$ using the quadratic formula.

Comment: @user477343 Ah ok thanks; so this should not be too difficult to pick up with a lot of practice.

Comment: @Ovi well as they say, *Practice makes perfect!*

Comment: @Fricul38 we are given $x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 2(xy+yz+zx)$ so $(x^2+y^2+z^2 - 2(xy+yz+xz)) \ge 0$. so $4xz + $ non.negative number $\ge 4xz$.

Comment: @achille hui wow thank you very much for the in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Since $$2(xy+xz+yz)-x^2-y^2-z^2)=$$
$$=(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{z})(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z})(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{x})\leq0,$$
We obtain $$\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{x}\leq0.$$
Thus, $$\frac{x}{z}\geq\frac{(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z})^2}{z}\geq4.$$
The equality occurs for $y=z$, which says that we got a minimal value.